# Android 7.0 on LG G-Pad X8.0 doesn't allow restricted profiles?

Tags: restricted-profiles

I have followed the instructions on setting up a restricted account on Android 7.0, but on my LG G-Pad X8.0, the Add User section doesn't have an option to selected regarding restricting an account.

What gives? Was this feature really removed?

Comment: Possibly. The system integrator (i.e. LG) can choose whether to include the feature or disable it.

Answer (score 0):

If your device have a SIM card port (the chip which is used to be able to make phone calls and access the internet through 3G or 4G, no Wi Fi) then it is considered a MOBILE PHONE. Restricted Profiles are not supported on mobile phones:

"Phone options

Unfortunately, restricted profiles aren’t available on Android phones running any version of the OS. It’s a logistical problem, claims a Google engineer, since phones are used for calls and texting, and restricting access could make the device owner miss such things."

http://www.greenbot.com/article/2949895/android/how-to-make-your-android-device-safe-for-kids.html